# Test command: Readable test fails

Tags: command-line, bash

I got a folder and a file in my home directory with this structure: `~/folder/file`.

Both folder and file got full permissions for me (folder is 700, file is 600).The following test command (it's inside a shell script if that matters) returns unexpectedly (imo) false.

```
[ -r ~/folder/file ]
echo $? #Prints 1->Failure
```

However if I use an alternative path to the file like

```
pwd #Prints /home/myname
[ -r /home/myname/folder/file ]
[ -r folder/file ]
echo $? #Prints 0->Success
```

Am I missing something?

`test -r` returns true if `FILE` exists and read permission is granted
according to 
`man test`.

Comment: Put `set -x; type -a [` inside the script before the test, and add the output of the type command the shell script log for the test command, please. How are you executing the script?

Comment: Did you use sudo? sudo will look for /root/folder/file

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem after all.The thing is i was reading the path from the keyboard(read command) and somehow the tilde(~) was not expanding.Solution to this was:

```
echo 'Give path:'
read var1
var2=$(eval echo "$var1");
```

Now var2 contains the full path(expanding the ~) and i could use my tests normally after that.

Comment: It could be worth to post the entire script next time . Whatever maybe you can simplify your code in a way as this:  `read var1 ; [ -r "$(eval echo "$var1")" ]; echo $?`. Or within bash you can use `[[`: `read var1 ; [[ -r $(eval echo "$var1") ]]; echo $?`.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement [Alator's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018850/295286), it should be noted that [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion) is performed only in these cases:

- Variable assignment, unquoted `~` immediately following `:`, as in `mypath=~/Documents:~/usr/share/stuff`
- Variable assignment following first `=`,  `~` unquoted, as in `foo=~/bar`
- Beginning of a "word": `~/ascript.sh`
- Separate "word": `stat ~/afile.txt`

`read` takes literal sequence of characters from `stdin` and doesn't perform Tilde Expansion; more importantly Tilde Expansion is performed by shell itself not its individual builtin commands.

One way to deal with that could be via `eval` as Alator showed, or one could make use of parameter substitution (which technically is just manual way of doing exactly same thing ):

```
~$ echo "${foo/\~/$HOME}"
/home/username/Documents
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind starting another process (or you have to deal with those particular languages) you can use Python and Perl like so:

```
python -c 'import sys,os; print os.path.expanduser(sys.argv[1])' "$foo"
perl -e 'print glob qq("$ARGV[0]")' "$foo" "$foo"
```